# Python, Selenium: Take a Full-Page Screenshot as .pdf Without Page Breaks, Regardless of Page Dimensions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Currently, I see it is possible to create screenshots with Selenium. However, they are always `.png` files. How can I take the same style screenshot but as `.pdf`?

Required style: No margins; Same dimensions as current page (like a full page screenshot)
Printing the page doesn't accomplish this because of all the formatting that comes with printing.

How I currently get a screenshot:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Function to find page size
S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Screen 
height = S('Height')
width = S('Width')

driver.set_window_size(width, height)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(PNG_SAVEAS)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, I found a solution that was not readily available elsewhere.

The key is to dynamically configure the width and height of the PDF page to match the content being printed. Additionally, I discovered that scaling down the result to only 1% of its original size speeds up the process significantly.

One thing to note is that when using GeckoDriver, I encountered a bug ([reference](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12066)) that caused the resulting PDF to be printed with the wrong size. However, I found that multiplying the size by `2.5352112676056335` resolved the issue. It's still unclear to me why this specific constant is relevant to my answer, but without applying this fix the PDF's aspect ratio is distorted (rather than scaled down proportionally to ~39% its desired size). The distortion results in a multi-page .pdf file, which is not the intended outcome.

This method was tested with GeckoDriver. If you are using Chrome, it is likely that you won't need the `RATIO_MULTIPLIER` workaround.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.print_page_options import PrintOptions
import base64

# Bug in geckodriver... seems unrelated, but this wont work otherwise.
# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12066
RATIO_MULTIPLIER = 2.5352112676056335

# Function to find page size
S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)

# Scale for PDF size. 1 for no change takes long time
pdf_scaler = .01

# Browser options. Headless is more reliable for screenshots in my exp.
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

# Lanuch webdriver, navigate to destination
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Find full page dimensions regardless of scroll
height = S('Height')
weight = S('Width')

# Dynamic setting of PDF page dimensions
print_options = PrintOptions()
print_options.page_height = (height*pdf_scaler)*RATIO_MULTIPLIER
print_options.page_width = (weight*pdf_scaler)*RATIO_MULTIPLIER
print_options.shrink_to_fit = True

# Prints to PDF (returns base64 encoded data. Must save)
pdf = driver.print_page(print_options=print_options)
driver.close()

# save the output to a file.
with open('example.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(base64.b64decode(pdf))
```

Versions used:

```
geckodriver 0.31.0
Firefox 113.0.1
selenium==4.9.1
Python 3.11.2
Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from PIL import Image

def get_page_size(driver):
    return driver.execute_script('return [document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight];')

def scroll_to_bottom(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

def capture_screenshot_as_pdf(driver, file_path):
    driver.save_screenshot(file_path)

def convert_to_pdf(input_file, output_file):
    image = Image.open(input_file)
    image.save(output_file, 'PDF', resolution=100.0)

# Set up the Firefox driver with options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), capabilities=capabilities)

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Get the page size
page_size = get_page_size(driver)

# Set the window size
driver.set_window_size(page_size[0], page_size[1])

# Scroll to the bottom to load dynamic content
scroll_to_bottom(driver)

# Capture the full-page screenshot as PNG
png_file_path = 'full_page_screenshot.png'
capture_screenshot_as_pdf(driver, png_file_path)

# Convert the PNG screenshot to PDF
pdf_file_path = 'full_page_screenshot.pdf'
convert_to_pdf(png_file_path, pdf_file_path)

# Clean up and close the browser
driver.quit()
```

This code captures a full-page screenshot as a PNG file and then converts it to a PDF file. Adjust the file paths (png_file_path and pdf_file_path) to your desired locations for saving the files.

Comment: This is a valid solution, although it goes through additional overhead of converting a .png file to a .pdf file. The .pdf will retain the original quality of the .png, which in my case was quite poor (though I'm sure there are solutions to be found for this). My solution will natively take a .pdf while retaining the original page dimensions (same as a .png would). In my experience, the picture quality of the .pdf yielded via this method surpasses the quality of the .png or .png->.pdf significantly. Please take a look at my answer. Currently, I'm trying to find any way to enable embeded links.